# Нарисовать фигуру из * на Java

Tags: java

```
int z = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < z; i++) {
    for (int a = 0; a < z; a++) {
        if (a>i) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        } else {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Выходит так:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

нужно так:

```
    *  
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
for (int a = z; a >= 0; a--) {
```